How to avoid circular import in this website and also add class to migration successfully
I’m working on a Flask application with SQLAlchemy and Flask-Migrate. I have a circular import issue that I can't seem to resolve. Here's a simplified version of my project structure:
Website1
|- app.py
|- models.py
|- form.py
|- templates

code for app.py :
import os
from flask import Flask , render_template , url_for , redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from models import Person
from form import AddForm , DelForm

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir,'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Migrate(app,db)


    

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add_person' , methods=['GET' , 'POST'])
def add_person():
    # from models import Person
    form = AddForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data 
        age = form.age.data 
        p1 = Person(name , age)
        db.session.add(p1)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('list_guys'))
    return render_template('add.html' , form=form)

@app.route('/del_form' , methods=['POST' , 'GET'])
def del_form():
    # from models import Person
    form = DelForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        id = form.id.data 
        m = db.session.get(Person,id)
        db.session.delete(m)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('list_guys'))
    return render_template('del.html', form=form)


@app.route('/list_guys')
def list_guys():
    # from models import Person
    people1 = Person.query.all()
    return render_template('list.html', people1=people1 )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

code for models.py :
from app import db

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key =True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self , name , age):
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name} has a age of {self.age}"
    
    
        

When I try to run my application, I encounter a circular import error because models.py imports db from app.py, and app.py imports Person from models.py. If I move the import of Person to inside the route functions in app.py, it resolves the circular import issue, but then I face problems when using Flask-Migrate. The Person table does not get created in the database, and I receive errors when trying to add objects.
How can I properly structure my Flask application to avoid circular import issues while still allowing Flask-Migrate to work correctly? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Extract all the portion that is needed to define db to a new file and import from it instead

I solved it using init.py and creating the database and migrate function in it.
